# How does Configuration.addResource() method work in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Does Configuration.addResource() method load resource file like ClassLoader of java or it just encapsulates ClassLoader class.Because I find it can not use **String** like "../resource.xml" as argument of addResource() to load resource file out of classpath, this property is just the same as ClassLoader.

Thx!

Comment: "How does it work" is a different question from "why is my usage not working for me?" Which do you really want to know?

Answer (score 6):

Browsing the Javadocs and source code for Configuration, Strings are assumed to be classpaths ([line 1162](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java.html)), rather than relative to the file system - you should use URLs to reference files on the local file system as follows:

```
conf.addResource(new File("../resource.xml").toURI().toURL());
```